# A problem on Riemann integration

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

I am stuck in proving that $$\sup_P L(P,f+g) = \sup_P L(P,f) + \sup_P L(P,g)$$.

where $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable. How to do ?

Comment: Have you been able to prove either $\leq$ or $\geq$?

Comment: yes now both. Thanks

Comment: Then perhaps you can post it as an answer, and allow people to have a look. This is a good way to earn some reputation as well :)